# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timewheel' python

Tags: python, time, job-scheduling

I have installed timewheel and also timewheel-scheduler on my mac.
Trying the following https://pypi.org/project/timewheel-scheduler/
However I am encountering the following error

```
from timewheel import TimeWheel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timewheel'
```

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Edit:

```
pip --version
pip 22.1.2 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

python --version
Python 3.7.4

pip show timewheel
Name: TimeWheel
Version: 0.0.5
Summary: Python implementation of time wheel,Task runer,Cache
Home-page: https://www.pkold.com
Author: zhenruyan
Author-email: baiyangwangzhan@hotmail.com
License: WTFPL
Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Edit 2

```
which python
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

```
echo $PATH
/Users/adrian/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Comment: The usual cause for this sort of error is that you installed the module for one version of Python, but then you're running the code under a different version of Python.

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install the module, and the exact command you used to run the code.

Comment: pip install timewheel
pip install timewheel-scheduler

Tried both python my_test.py & python3 my_test.py

Comment: Show us the output of these commands: `pip --version` and `python --version`

Comment: And also `pip show timewheel`

Comment: Edit the question to include those outputs, rather than adding as comments.  Much easier to read that way.

Comment: And there's the answer.  `pip` is Python 3.9, but `python` is Python 3.7.4.

Comment: Update your path and/or shell alias so that `python` is Python 3.9.

Comment: Done. what can I do about it?

Comment: How do I change it? Im new to python and mac both

Comment: For starters, show us the output of `which python`

Comment: And also `echo $PATH`

Comment: Edited the post with the details

Comment: Oh, you're using Anaconda!  I believe in that case, you're not really supposed to use `pip` to install packages -- you're supposed to use `conda`.

Comment: I am confused, I have home brew as well.
Can I use one for all pip/conda/brew, one of them

Comment: How do pip, conda and homebrew compare.
Earlier I used pip to install schedule and it worked fine

Comment: `pip` is specifically for installing Python-related things.  `brew` is for installing software of any sort, completely unrelated to Python.  And I don't really know much more about `conda`.

Comment: which python
/usr/local/bin/python

python --version
Python 3.9.0

Comment: Changed, and I still have the same problem with time wheel...

Comment: Dare I ask how you ended up with so many versions of Python installed on your mac?  Looking at your PATH output, there appear to be at least four...

Comment: When I try to install TimeWheel again with pip it says 
Requirement already satisfied: TimeWheel in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.0.5)

Comment: Show us the output of this code in Python: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: ['/Users/adrian/Desktop/Tutes/Python/schedule', '/Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python39.zip', '/Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9', '/Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Comment: Ok, well that's the answer again.  `pip` is using `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, but `python` is using `/Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

Comment: Ok, may I ask how I change this is bash profile?

Comment: If I were you I'd try to find the python executable in `/Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2` (probably in the `bin` subdirectory), and make `python` a shell alias that points to it.  Or maybe just alter your PATH so that `/Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/bin` comes first.

Comment: This is all my bash profile has, how do I change it
'
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export EDITOR="code -w"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
'

Comment: You're getting beyond my expertise.  You might try asking in the Apple-specific board https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: /Users/adrian/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/bin:/Users/adrian/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/adrian/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:

Comment: I changed it, still the same issue